# How can I reference recordset names in the output section of my cloudformation script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

I am creating some DNS entries in my cloudformation.  There is a param passed into the cfn script, which results in the creation of a Route53 entry like hostname-test.example.com:

```
"Host" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup",
  "Properties" : {
      "HostedZoneName" : "example.com.",
      "RecordSets" : [
        {
          "Name" : { 
            "Fn::Join" : [ "-", [
                {"Ref" : "Hostname" },
                "test.example.com"
            ]]
          },
          "Type" : "A",
          "AliasTarget" : {
            "DNSName" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "PublicWebLoadBalancer", "CanonicalHostedZoneName" ] },
            "HostedZoneId" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "PublicWebLoadBalancer", "CanonicalHostedZoneNameID" ] }
          }
        }
      ]
  }
}
```

In my output, I would like to get the Name attribute from the RecordSet, but I don't know how to reference it.  According to the [Fn::GetAtt documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html), Route53 objects are not supported.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

This question is a bit old, but it I just ran into this same issue. 
You need to output the entire RecordSet, ie:

```
"Outputs" : {
  "MyDNSRecord" : {
    "Description": "The DNS Record of ...",
    "Value" : { "Ref": "MyRecordSet" }
  }
}
```

Which (not intuitively) outputs the value of the record set name you are looking for.

Comment: This answer is correct, but was not initially clear to me. I have added a similar answer for yaml.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question, and was looking for a clear answer in yaml.

Given the following AWS::Route53::RecordSet

```
rPublicReverseProxyNLBDnsRecord:
  Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
  Properties:
    HostedZoneName: !Ref pPublicHostedZoneName
    Comment:  !Sub 'DNS record for the ${AWS::StackName} ELB front door.'
    Name: !Sub '${pDeploymentType}.${pPublicHostedZoneName}'
    Type: CNAME
    TTL: '30'
    ResourceRecords:
      - !GetAtt rPublicReverseProxyNLB.DNSName
```

I was able to output the Application URL I wanted with the following output section code:

```
Outputs:

  ApplicationURL:
    Description: 'The public URL for the application'
    Value: !Sub 'https://${rPublicReverseProxyNLBDnsRecord}/'
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of embedding your RecordSet inside the RecordSetGroup, define it as a separate property, with the same HostedZoneName as your RecordSetGroup.

You can then use "Ref" to get the value of the Name attribute.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-recordset.html

Answer (score -1):

I second the suggestion of trying *RecordSet*.

But your "Name" is deterministic. If the stack completes, outputting what you already have will never behave differently from what you want:

```
          { 
            "Fn::Join" : [ "-", [
                {"Ref" : "Hostname" },
                "test.example.com"
            ]]
          }
```

If this were OOP, I'd say it's decidedly wrong to kick back an argument without taking the opportunity to implicitly test the function.